# Pressure sensitivity on GIMP 2.10.6 causing cursor to offset

Tags: gimp

So I had reinstalled the new gimp, everything was fine while I was setting it up.

The cursor was on point for drawing or just clicking on options. But as soon as I set the option for screen mode, to allow it to pick up pressure on the stylus, the actual point of the paint brush rose higher than the point of the stylus.

It's fine with clicking options, or other tools, but as soon as it moves onto the canvas, it moves up. Using the mouse, it doesn't move, only the stylus pen.

I tried messing around with it a few times, but I just got too fed up with it. The black dot is where the stylus sits, and the circle is where it actually draws.

[image: illustration of the gap between where the stylus sits and where it draws]